# Number close to another : How to explain it?

Tags: approximation, rational-numbers, tangent-line, lambert-w

Let $0<x<1$ then define :

$$f(x)=x^{\operatorname{W}\left(x^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)}$$
$$g(x)=2-f(1-x)$$
$$h(x)=g'(0.5)(x-0.5)+g(0.5)$$
$$p(x)=g'(0.2)(x-0.2)+g(0.2)$$
Where we have the Lambert's function

Now denotes by $a$ the solution of $h(x)=p(x)$

We have $$a=0.378333357\cdots\simeq \frac{227}{600}=0.378333333\cdots$$

---

[image: Graphic-problem]

As you can see with the picture it's an attempt to evaluate an integral with tangent line wich conducts me to that .

---

Question :

How to explain that $a$ is so close to a rational number ?Is it a pure coincidence or not ?

Thanks

Comment: In the grand scheme of things it really doesn't seem that close.  If you round *any* irrational to $4$ digits it's close to a rational number $\frac K{10000}$.  This one happens to have four $3$s in it which means we can make it close to rational with a denominator a multiple of $30$. The question really is why does it have four $3$s in a row early on and .... well, why not?

Comment: Some words describing the colored lines and curves in the picture would help me see what there relates $a$ to that rational number.

Comment: Hi Erik ! Suppose that you have the equation $a_1+b_1x=a_2+b_2 x$ where aii coefficients are irrational. What is the probability that $x$ is a rational number ? This could be a good question. Cheers :-)

Comment: The string $378333357$ occurs at position $107187890$ in $\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analytical solution of $h(x)=p(x)$ is
$$x=\frac 1 2+\frac{3 g'\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)+10
   \left(g\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)-g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{10
   \left(g'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-g'\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)}$$ Rigorously computed,
$$x=0.37833335765982278759994763708813774613464205787232352995953078149548\cdots$$

Rationalized it could be
$$\left\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{3}{8},\frac{11}{29},\frac{14}{37},\frac{199}{526},\color{red}{\frac{22
   7}{600}},\frac{18401}{48637},\frac{24984}{66037},\frac{25892}{684
   37},\frac{155579}{411222},\frac{207363}{548096},\frac{2877190}{7604907},\cdots\right\}$$
Then why not
$$ \sin \left(\frac{2557  }{20704}\pi\right)\quad \text{or} \quad \tan \left(\frac{538  }{4673}\pi\right)\quad \text{or} \quad W\left(\frac{16033}{29029}\right)$$